# Online Pygame - Move Ball Simultaneously on Two Screens

Tags: python, networking, pygame

I am making an online/multiplayer pong game in pygame and the issue that I have now is that the ball starts moving immediately when a player connects and hits play [**like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W1UM.jpg). I want the ball to start moving once two players have connected and not before. I tried to make a `Game` class which would have a `boolean` flip to `True` once two players have connected. In the redrawWindow function in the client.py file I am checking if the boolean in the `Game` class is true and when it is, the ball start moving, or well.. is supposed to. However, I am getting a strange error and I don't understand why. I don't even know if this is the best way to go about it but I couldn't think of another way to retrieve the number of players from the server.py.

```
if not Game.connected():
TypeError: connected() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

**The server.py file**

```
num_players = 0
game = Game()
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", addr)
    num_players += 1
    if num_players == 2:
        game.two_players_connected = True

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, currentPlayer))
```

**The Game class**

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.two_players_connected = False

    def connected(self):
        return self.two_players_connected
```

**The redrawWindow function in the client.py file**

```
def redrawWindow(win, player, player2, ball):
    win.blit(BG, (0, 0))
    if not Game.connected():
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 80)
        text = font.render("Waiting for Player...", 1, (255, 0, 0), True)
        win.blit(text, (WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2, HEIGHT / 2 - text.get_height() / 2))
    else:
        # Code to move and display the ball and paddles
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling `.connected()` on the *definition* of the class, not an *instance* of the class (and connected() is not a static member function).  Maybe it's just a typo.

```
def redrawWindow(win, player, player2, ball):
    win.blit(BG, (0, 0))
    if not Game.connected():                           # <-- HERE
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 80)
```

You probably meant:

```
if not game.connected():                               # <-- HERE (lower case 'G')
```

Comment: Oh I thought I could just access the Game class immediately.. Well that doesn't work either because 'game' is in the server file, which I as a client am not supposed to access just like that right.. So I think I would have to go about it a different way. Maybe when two players are connected I send that information do each client. Only problem is I have no idea how to do that..